# jquery mobile display loader onsubmit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

working on a jquery mobile app where a user can login. i have a loader on the form that i want to display on submit of the form so the user can know the form is been processed. i've searched the web and found some scripts but doesn't seem to work for me. so i've decide to paste my html here if i would get some help

```
<form id="form5" name="form1" method="post" action="check.asp" target="_parent">
          <table width="270" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Email</strong></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><label for="textfield6"><span id="sprytextfield1"><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter your Email Address</span><span id="sprytextfield8">
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" />
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter your Email</span></span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Password</strong></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><label for="textfield7"><span id="sprytextfield2"><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Password is required</span><span id="sprytextfield9">
                <input name="password" type="text" class="round" id="password" />
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter your Password</span></span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;
                 <button  id="login">Login</button></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="127"><a href="#register">Register</a></td>
              <td width="122"><div align="right"><a href="#fpassword">Forgot Password</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><img src="../imgs/loader.png" width="30" height="29" style="display:none" id="img"/>&nbsp;<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="img/loader.png" alt="" />Loading!</div>
                <img src="../imgs/loader.png" width="30" height="29" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <table width="450" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr> </tr>
            <tr> </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: are you using ajax submit??

Comment: yes i use ajax submit

Answer (score 0):

### From your comment I got that you're using ajax for form submit.

In your HTML put a pre-loader markup. (in yours image with `id="img"`)

### Then use this

```
$('#img')
    .hide()  // Hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```